# General questions for Quantum Atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry

1. How does electrons exist as waves?
2. How do electrons change its direction and amplitudes?
3. How is it possible that electrons exist as both waves and particles?
4. What does paralle spins refers to in Hunds’rule. why does parallel allow a low energy state?
5. How does DeBroglie’s work(wave duality) differentiate from Heisenberg’s uncertainty rule?
6. what does direction mean for electron?
7. What does it mean for fundamental and harmonic wave when talking about the orbital(s,p,d)? Why fundamental wave is lowest possible energy and harmonic waves are highest possible energy
8. How does Plank’t work on quantanized energy help us to understand electrons?

Comment: Hi. How do you exist? It' s indeed the same question, regarding it' s base of thought: why should it not "exist" like this?

Comment: These questions would require a course in basic quantum theory to answer properly.

Comment: This video is helpful for "understanding" quantum mechanics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Z8Ma2YT8vY.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is a great site for physics questions and answers. To keep the quality high, we have some guidelines. For example, please ask *one* question per post.

Comment: Could you please explain in details what research you have done on your own on each of your questions, what concepts you have diligently studied to understand quantum mechanics, and what specific difficulties have you had understanding the subject matter references relevant to your questions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. How does electrons exist as waves?

A thing exist for us by direct observation and recognition, say a chair or a table. Or a thing exist for us by deduction and abstraction from some phenomena. The existence of electrons as charged particles was deduced from the observation of electric currents, the [oil drop experiment by Millikan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Andrews_Millikan), the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect), ...

The wave nature first was proposed by de Broglie as a reaction of [Bohrs model of orbiting electrons in atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model):

> > Bohr's condition, that the angular momentum is an integer multiple of ħ was later reinterpreted in 1924 by de Broglie as a standing wave condition: the electron is described by a wave and a whole number of wavelengths must fit along the circumference of the electron's orbit.

The assumption, that electrons orbit around nucleus was rejected later, but the assumption about that “whole number of wavelengths must fit along the circumference of the electron's orbit” is virulent.

> 2. How do electrons change its direction and amplitudes?

Firstly under the influence of an electric field, acting not in a straight line to the direction of the electrons movement. Secondly by a magnetic field, which acts non-parallel to the electrons movement [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force). Thirdly nearby edges ([excerpt of mine about electron deflection](https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges)).

If you refer to the fringes from the deflection of electrons behind edges for the calculation of the amplitude of these fringes then these amplitudes are a function of the kinetic energy resp. the velocity of the electrons. If under amplitude you mean something else please ask a separate question.

> 3. How is it possible that electrons exist as both waves and particles?
>      What does parallel spins refers to in Hunds rule. Why does parallel allow a low energy state?

Do they? In a lot of observations they exist as particles and behind edges from the observation of periodical intensity distribution (fringes) it is concluded about the existence of a wave characteristics (Bohrs model isn’t in use anymore).

About spin there is an inaccurate language. The electron has only one value for its spin. The positron has the same but of different sign value.

In atoms only two electrons could be in the same state and only of the ***orientations*** of their spins are anti-aligned. To make it less abstract, you can imagine this spin-disalignment by the associated with the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electrons. Imagine tiny bar magnets which are stacked together side by side.